Flutter SRTP / RTSPS Video Stream
I would like to fetch an SRTP / RTSPS video live stream in my Flutter app and display it in the app. Preferably as a Uint8List stream, but something else would also be okay.
Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

VLC or ffmpeg bindings !?

@Christoph I tried both but it seems that vlc does not support SRTP. And there was no possibility to access the audio data with ffmpeg
